# Executing command in bash with argument with space in it

Tags: bash

I have a problem with executing some of the commands using bash. Let's say I have a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="sh -c \"ls\""
$cmd
```

This works all fine. However, if I alter the argument for the command to contain space:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="sh -c \"ls -a\""
$cmd
```

then it throws `-a": 1: -a": Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string` error. It seems that bash correctly noticed open quote, but it stops looking for closing quote on a first space. If I change `$cmd` to `echo $cmd` it returns `sh -c "ls -a"` as expected. If I execute this command in terminal everything works, but `$(./mysh.sh)` fails with same error.

I have tried escaping the space with `\`, or 'double-escape' quotes with `\\\"` (silly idea, but was worth a try). Could anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd be better off storing commands in functions:

```
cmd() {
    sh -c "ls -a"
}
cmd
```

Or in arrays:

```
cmd=(sh -c "ls -a")
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Using plain string variables simply won't work. You'd have to use `eval`, which is [not a great idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). Functions are much better.

```
cmd="sh -c \"ls -a\""
eval "$cmd"
```

Comment: @BroiSatse: As for why `eval` is generally not a good idea for _security_ reasons: it allows execution of _any_ command stored in a string - if the string was handed to you, you'd have to trust its contents to only do what you expect it to. `eval` may be fine in limited and controlled circumstances, but generally it's best to stay away (and there are often better alternatives, as in this case) - see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Comment: @mklement0 Excellent answer. That's better than what I had written.

Answer (score 3):

Repeated applications of quoting rules can be complicated. First I will explain what is going wrong:

```
cmd="sh -c \"ls -a\""
$cmd
```

One of the first things Bash does when executing $cmd is split it up on whitespace characters: so you get a command with three arguments, equivalent to this:

```
sh -c "\"ls" "-a\""
```

Already you can see where this is going wrong. Some solutions have already been posted, but generally for each level of shell command processing the command will be subjected to, you need to provide another level of guard characters to maintain the original intended meaning:

```
# To execute the command "ls -a" in a shell:
sh -c "ls -a"
# Two shells deep:
sh -c "sh -c ls\\ -a"    # Backslash protects space from being treated as an argument separator by first level of shell processing
```

It's better to avoid repeat application of quote-guarding if you can...

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd="sh -c \"ls -a\""
eval $cmd
```